Takesaki Lemma 1.26, Chapter V
I was reading the following lemma and encountered the quesion, which might be simple: why "If $\varphi_i(f_j) = 0$, then $z e_i f_j z e_i = 0$; hence $z e_i f_j e_i = 0$, and so $z f_j e_i = 0$. "
What I tried: since $z e_i$ is the support, $ze_i f_j ze_i=0$, and $z$ is a projection in $\mathcal Z$, $0=z e_i f_j ze_i=z^2e_if_je_i=ze_if_je_i$ and equals to $e_i (z f_je_i)e_i$. So, By the isomorphism $\sigma_i$, it suffices to show $z f_j e_i\in\mathcal{Z}$. Is this possible?

Lemma 1.26. Let $z$ be a central projection in $\mathcal{M}$. If $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{f_j\}_{j \in J}$ are two orthogonal families of abelian projections such that $z(e_i) = z(f_j) = z$ for any $i \in I$ and $j \in J$, and if $\sum_{i \in I} e_i = z = \sum_{j \in J} f_j$, then the cardinal numbers of $I$ and $J$ are equal.
Proof. Considering $\mathcal{M}_z$, we assume that $z = 1$. By the previous lemma, $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{f_j\}_{j \in J}$ are mutually equivalent and $e_i \sim f_j$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the cardinal numbers of $I$ and $J$, respectively. By Proposition 1.22, $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{M}_{e}\bar\otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{H}_1)\cong\mathcal{M}_{f_1}\bar\otimes\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{H}_2)$, where $\dim \mathfrak{H}_1 = \alpha$ and $\dim \mathfrak{H}_2 = \beta$. Since $e_1$ and $f_1$ are both abelian projections with $z(e_1) = z(f_1) = 1$, $\mathcal{M}_e \cong \mathcal{M}_f \cong \mathcal{Z}$, where $\mathcal{Z}$ is the center of $\mathcal{M}$.
If $\alpha$ is finite, then we may consider the $\mathcal{Z}$-valued trace $\Phi$ defined by (1) based on the tensor product decomposition $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{M}_e \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{H}_1) \cong \mathcal{Z} \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{H}_1)$. Since $e_i \sim f_j$, we have $\Phi(e_i) = \Phi(f_j)$ for every $(i,j) \in I \times J$. Hence we have
$$
\alpha \Phi(e_1) = \sum_{i \in I} \Phi(e_i) = \Phi(1) = 1 = \sum_{j \in J} \Phi(f_j) = \beta \Phi(f_1),\tag{1}
$$
so that $\alpha = \beta$.
Suppose $\alpha$ is infinite. By symmetry, $\beta$ is infinite. Let $\varphi$ be a normal state of $\mathcal{Z}$. Since the map $\sigma_i : x\in\mathcal{Z} \mapsto x e_i\in e_i \mathcal{M}e_i$ is an isomorphism, we can define a normal state $\varphi_i$ on $\mathcal{M}$ by $\varphi_i(x) = \varphi \circ \sigma_i^{-1}(e_i x e_i)$, $x \in \mathcal{M}$, $i \in I$. Let $z$ be the support of $\varphi$ in $\mathcal{Z}$. It follows that the support of $\varphi_i$ is $z e_i$ for each $i \in I$. For each $i \in I$, let $J_i = \{j \in J : \varphi_i(f_j) \neq 0\}$. Since $\{f_j\}_{j \in J}$ is orthogonal, $J_i$ is countable. If $\varphi_i(f_j) = 0$, then $z e_i f_j z e_i = 0$; hence $z e_i f_j e_i = 0$, and so $z f_j e_i = 0$. Since $\sum_{i \in I} z f_j e_i = z f_j \neq 0$, $\varphi_i(f_j) \neq 0$ for some $i \in I$. Hence $J = \bigcup_{i \in I} J_i$. Therefore we have $\beta \leq \alpha \aleph_0 = \alpha$, so that $\alpha = \beta$ by symmetry.
